# C# - MS Charts image becomes blank after saving it

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, mschart

I have a page that displays a generated MS chart according to the selected options.

Previously when doing it on my local, I could save the chart image and display it in an excel sheet through ExcelDl_Click. But after deploying the system to the IIS, the saved "chart" image that I get is a blank square image.

Here is the code which is used on both the local and in deployment:

```
    protected void ExcelDl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ViewHistoryChart.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        Chart1.RenderControl(hw);

        string tmpChartName = "ChartImage.jpg";
        string imgPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + tmpChartName;
        Chart1.SaveImage(imgPath);

        string src = tmpChartName;
        string img = string.Format("<img src = '{0}{1}' />", HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, src);

        Table table = new Table();
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        Unit width = new Unit(500, UnitType.Pixel);
        row.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
        row.Cells[0].Width = width;
        row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(new Label { Text = ChartTitle.Text,  ForeColor=Color.Red, });
        table.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new TableRow();
        row.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
        row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = lblSectionFunctionSelected.Text });
        table.Rows.Add(row);
        row = new TableRow();
        row.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
        row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = img });
        table.Rows.Add(row);
        row.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
        row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = lbllegendHistory.Text });
        table.Rows.Add(row);

        sw = new StringWriter();
        hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        table.RenderControl(hw);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

When I click on the ChartImg.axd image link on the page, the chart is displayed correctly. But after I click on ExcelDl_Click, the link will display nothing after reopening it. I have a feeling that it has something to do with how I save the image but I'm not sure. Are there any package updates needed to solve this issue? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're having this issue is that the web application isn't able to save to the server's local file system.  So when you do  `Chart1.SaveImage(imgPath);` it doesn't actually save.  If you're going to stick with this pattern the app pool user would need write permissions on this folder.

Comment: Okay, I've tried doing this and it's still saved as the same white square image. I've even tried to give full access to the AppPool. Your answer seems to suggest that there is a different alternative? What else can I do?